# Como bindear src de imagenes en Nuxt.js y Vuetify.js

Tags: vue.js

Mi problema radica en lo siguiente:

Cuando intento bindear el atributo src de la etiqueta img y lo pruebo en el navegador no carga como deberia la imagen

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            src: 'static/img/slide/slider-01.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: 'static/img/slide/slider-02.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: 'static/img/slide/slider-03.jpg'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-carousel delimiter-icon="stop">
      <v-carousel-item v-for="(item,i) in items" v-bind:src="'~/static/img/slide/' + item.src" :key="i">
        <img :src=item.src alt="">
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </div>
</template>
```

el en navegador lo que recibo es esto:

```html
<img src="static/img/slide/slider-01.jpg" alt="">
```

a diferencia de otras imagenes que coloco sin necesidad de un v-for ni bindeo, de estas ultima recibo algo como esto:

```html
<img src="/_nuxt/img/cp-white.39b6f30.png" alt="cp-white.png">
```

si alguien me ayudara se lo agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resuelto, mi error estaba en que estaba llamando a las imágenes de la siguiente manera:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            src: 'static/img/slide/slider-01.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: 'static/img/slide/slider-02.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: 'static/img/slide/slider-03.jpg'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

cuando tenia que llamarlas de la siguiente manera:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            src: 'img/slide/slider-01.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: 'img/slide/slider-02.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: 'img/slide/slider-03.jpg'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

cambiando la ruta d ela imagen por `'img/slide/slider-01.jpg'` en vez de `'static/img/slide/slider-01.jpg'`

Aunque aun no entendio a cual es la razón para que así funcione, lo cierto es que así funciona.